# Angular2 - 'Can't resolve all parameters' error while injecting http into a custom service

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-modules

I have built an **ErrorHandlerLogger** which is a service which extends ErrorHandler and logs error messages into a remote repository.

**ErrorHandlerLogger** requires the Angular **http** client provided by the **HttpModule**.

In the **ErrorHandlerModule** I import **HttpModule** and define **ErrorHandlerLogger** as provider.

In the **AppModule** I import **ErrorHandlerModule**.

When I launch the app I get the following error message

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorHandlerLogger: (?).
```

Here my code

**ErrorHandlerModule**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import {ErrorHandlerLogger} from './error-handler-logger';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],
    imports: [
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerLogger}
    ]
})
export class ErrorHandlerModule {}
```

**ErrorHandlerLogger**

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import './rxjs-operators';

export class ErrorHandlerLogger extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
     }

    handleError(error) {
        // my logic
    }

}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {ErrorHandlerModule} from './error-manager/error-handler.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    ErrorHandlerModule
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```ts
@Injectable() // <<<=== required if the constructor has parameters 
export class ErrorHandlerLogger extends ErrorHandler {
```

Comment: Thanks. Right and super-fast.

Comment: According to the Angular2 style guide, `@Injectable()` should just always be added to injectables because it's easy to forget when parameters are added later (which is quite common).

Comment: Thanks for saving my day :)))