# Angular 2 TypeScript Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ProductsService

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am getting the following: "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ProductsService".

Ref: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-data-binding

**product.model.ts**

```
export class Product {
constructor(
    public ProductID?: number,
    public ProductName?: string,
    public UnitPrice?: number,
    public UnitsInStock?: number,
    public Discontinued?: boolean
) { } }
```

**products.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Jsonp, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

// See: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-data-binding

export class ProductsService {
    constructor( private jsonp: Jsonp) { }

    fetchData(action: string = "", data?: Product): Observable<Product[]>{
        console.log("BGW Action: " + action);
        console.log("BGW this.serializeModels(data) = " + this.serializeModels(data));
        return this.jsonp.get(`http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK${this.serializeModels(data)}`).map(response => response.json())
    }

    private serializeModels(data?: Product): string {
        return data ? `&models=${JSON.stringify([data])}` : '';
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

Contains:

```
import { ProductsService } from './products.service';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

And:

```
providers: [ProductsService],
```

And:

```
public productsData: Array<Product> = [];
// public listItems: Array<string> = [];
```

And:

```
//constructor (@Inject(ProductsService) private productService: ProductsService) { }
constructor (private productService: ProductsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.productService.fetchData().subscribe(
    (data) => this.productsData = data
  )
}
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Regards,

Ben

Comment: Your fetchData accepts two parameters, `action` and `data`, but where you call the method, you arent passing any parameters...

Comment: Have you registered the `JsonpModule` in your app.module?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this, in **app.component.ts** I changed:

```
constructor (private productsService: ProductsService) { }
```

to

```
constructor (@Inject(ProductsService) private productsService: ProductsService) { }
```

In **product.service.ts**, change:

```
constructor( private jsonp: Jsonp) { }
```

to:

```
constructor(@Inject(Jsonp) private jsonp: Jsonp) { }
```

Comment: Thanks! using `@Inject(...)` in `constructor` solved an error being unable to inject __anything__ into `HttpInterceptor`

Comment: Turned out I was missing an 
`@Injectable()` decorator on my `export class AuthService extends HttpInterceptor { // ... code }` as was solved on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847356/angular2-cant-resolve-all-parameters-error-while-injecting-http-into-a-cust